# Как удалить комментарии ревьюера в vs code после мерджа пулл реквеста?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, pull-request

На картинке пример всплывающего комментария. Стрелочка в правом верхнем углу сворачивает коммент.
[image: скрин экрана]

Comment: Скорее это комментарий не в vs code, а в пулл реквесте на гитхабе.

Comment: Да, безусловно, но у меня стоит плагин для vs code GitHub Pull Requests and Issues и он видимо подтягивает данные комменты, в документации к плагину не нашел инфы - вот думаю может кто-то сталкивался

Comment: Эти комментарии продолжают лежать на гитхабе, соответственно и подтягиваются, да. Удалить их нельзя, разве что удалить с гитхаба.